# equivalent in vb.net of c# code

Tags: vb.net

In C# we can pick out some pieces of code by { }.

Can you tell me what analogue can I use in VB.NET?

Example in C#:

```
private void Pr1(bool DoPreform = true)
{
   Pr3(false);
   {
      Pr5(false);
      Pr7(false);
   }
   {
      Pr5(false);
   }
}
```

Comment: Do avoid writing pointless code.  Both in C# *and* VB.NET.  Those extra braces do nothing at all, C# is not C++.  Except confuse the dickens out of the reader of the code.  Well, you.

Comment: @HansPassant: those braces do define a scope block. Even though I'd certainly not recommend their use, and they're redundant in the code as posted, they don't quite do nothing. (E.g., this is valid within a function: `{ int a = 0; } { string a = ""; }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `If` statement with 'always true' condition, like that:

```
Private Sub Pr1()
    Pr3(False)
    If True Then
        Pr5(False)
        Pr7(False)
    End If

    If True Then
        Pr5(False)
    End IF
End Sub
```

There are free C# to VB.NET converters in the net, e.g. [here](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/)

Answer (score -1):

It is not really exists, instead there is the `END` statement,

You can see this links - they will help you in VB.
[Complete Comparison for VB.NET and C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9978/Complete-Comparison-for-VB-NET-and-C)

[WHAT A C# CODER SHOULD KNOW BEFORE THEY WRITE VB – UPDATED](http://blogs.msmvps.com/kathleen/2008/07/25/what-a-c-coder-should-know-before-they-write-vb-updated/)